# Julia: How to efficiently sort subarrays of 2 large arrays in parallel?

Tags: arrays, sorting, parallel-processing, julia

I have large 1D arrays `a` and `b`, and an array of pointers `I` that separates them into subarrays. My `a` and `b` barely fit into RAM and are of different dtypes (one contains `UInt32`s, the other `Rational{Int64}`s), so I don’t want to join them into a 2D array, to avoid changing dtypes.

For each `i in I[2:end]`, I wish to sort the subarray `a[I[i-1],I[i]-1]` and apply the same permutation to the corresponding subarray `b[I[i-1],I[i]-1]`. My attempt at this is:

```
function sort!(a,b) 
    p=sortperm(a); 
    a[:], b[:] = a[p], b[p]
    end
Threads.@threads for i in I[2:end] 
    sort!( a[I[i-1], I[i]-1],   b[I[i-1], I[i]-1] ) 
    end
```

However, already on a small example, I see that `sort!` does not alter the view of a subarray:

```
a, b = rand(1:10,10), rand(-1000:1000,10) .//1
sort!(a,b);     println(a,"\n",b)  # works like it should

a, b = rand(1:10,10), rand(-1000:1000,10) .//1
sort!(a[1:5],b[1:5]);     println(a,"\n",b)  # does nothing!!!
```

Any help on how to create such function `sort!` (as efficient as possible) are welcome.

---

**Background:** I am dealing with data coming from sparse arrays:

```
using SparseArrays
n=10^6;   x=sprand(n,n,1000/n); #random matrix with 1000 entries per column on average
x = SparseMatrixCSC(n,n,x.colptr,x.rowval,rand(-99:99,nnz(x)).//1); #chnging entries to rationals
U = randperm(n) #permutation of rows of matrix x
a, b, I = U[x.rowval], x.nzval, x.colptr;
```

Thus these `a,b,I` serve as good examples to my posted problem. What I am trying to do is sort the row indices (and corresponding matrix values) of entries in each column.

**Note:** I already asked this question on Julia discourse [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-efficiently-sort-subarrays-of-2-large-arrays-in-parallel/82771), but received no replies nor comments. If I can improve on the quality of the question, don't hesitate to tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `a[1:5]` is not a view, it's just a copy. instead make the view like

```
function sort!(a,b) 
    p=sortperm(a); 
    a[:], b[:] = a[p], b[p]
end
Threads.@threads for i in I[2:end] 
    sort!(view(a, I[i-1]:I[i]-1), view(b, I[i-1]:I[i]-1)) 
end
```

is what you are looking for

ps.

the `@view a[2:3]`, `@view(a[2:3])` or the `@views` macro can help making thins more readable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't redefine `Base.sort!` like this. Now, `sort!` will shadow `Base.sort!` and you'll get errors if you call `sort!(a)`.

Also, `a[I[i-1], I[i]-1]` and `b[I[i-1], I[i]-1]` are not slices, they are just single elements, so nothing should happen if you sort them either with `views` or not. And sorting arrays in a moving-window way like this is not correct.

What you want to do here, since your vectors are huge, is call `p = partialsortperm(a[i:end], i:i+block_size-1)` repeatedly in a loop, choosing a `block_size` that fits into memory, and modify both `a` and `b` according to `p`, then continue to the remaining part of `a` and find next `p` and repeat until nothing remains in `a` to be sorted. I'll leave the implementation as an exercise for you, but you can come back if you get stuck on something.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections and suggestions, I'll have a look at `partialsortperm` and try to implement it like you said. But why do you write "sorting arrays in a moving-window way like this is not correct"? I do not understand what's incorrect about it? I just want to sort every subarray of`a`, not the whole `a`. (In the end, I want to construct another sparse array with `SparseMatrixCSC(n,n,I,a,b)`) Also, doing independent sorting of disjoint subarrays is great for parallelization. Is that also the case with your suggested algorithm?